# How do I get SAS to fill in the missing record with the info from the most recent prior time the stock issue 04W traded?

Tags: sas

```
company issue   datadate    shares  price   mv_issue mv_day
4439    04W 19921006    1100    120 132000   454800
4439    05W 19921006    1400    115 161000   454800
4439    06W 19921006    800 101 80800    454800
4439    07W 19921006    900 90  81000    454800
**4439  04W 19921006    1100    120 132000   455500**missing
4439    05W 19921007    1400    116 162400   455500
4439    06W 19921007    800 99  79200    455500
4439    07W 19921007    900 91  81900    455500
5510    02W 19940126    50  5   250  1090
5510    03W 19940126    120 7   840  1090
5510    02W 19940127    50  5   250  1210
5510    03W 19940127    120 8   960  1210
```

**record is actually missing. How do I get SAS to fill in the missing record with the info from the most recent prior time the stock issue 04W traded?

I’m trying to calculate a market value as shares multiplied by price for each unique issue.  Then I want to sum the mv_issue over all issues that day.  I’ve done that here to show that for day 19921006, the total market value should be 454800.  But on day 1992/10/07, the record for 04W does not exist because this issue was not traded that day.  If I substitute the prior trading activity for 04W, as I’ve done in this dataset, the mv_day would be 455500.  How do I create this missing record such that the total for the day would include all possible stock issues for that company (04W using the prior day’s info, 05W, 06W, and 07W)?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use SAS proc expand for filling missing values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207593/use-sas-proc-expand-for-filling-missing-values)

Comment: You'll need to change the date to a valid SAS date if it isn't, but otherwise proc expand is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Old question I stumbled upon, but thought I'd answer an alternative to proc expand in case anybody sees this.

I'm a fan of using data steps when I can, if the desired action is simple enough. Last observation carried forward (LOCF) is simple in my mind. You don't need to update your date column to a true SAS date format if you don't want, though I'd personally recommend it. Just need any sorting index. Given dataset RAW which looks like:

```
     DATEC      |    DATEN   | VAL
01JAN2016T12:30   1767270600    1
01JAN2016T14:00   1767276000    2
01JAN2016T19:00   1767294000    5
02JAN2016T08:00   1767340800    3
06JAN2016T12:00   1767700800    .
21JAN2016T21:00   1769029200    8
03FEB2016T09:00   1770109200   10
13FEB2016T12:00   1770984000    6
21FEB2016T09:30   1771666200    .
15MAR2016T12:00   1773662400    .
20MAR2016T12:00   1774094400    5
```

Here's a quick piece of code I wrote up to handle this.

```
proc sort data=RAW; by daten; run;

data LOCF;
  retain LOCF;
  set RAW;
  if val ne . then LOCF=val;
  if val=. then val=LOCF;
  drop LOCF;
run;
```

The resulting dataset, LOCF, will look like this:

```
     DATEC      |    DATEN   | VAL
01JAN2016T12:30   1767270600    1
01JAN2016T14:00   1767276000    2
01JAN2016T19:00   1767294000    5
02JAN2016T08:00   1767340800    3
06JAN2016T12:00   1767700800    3**
21JAN2016T21:00   1769029200    8
03FEB2016T09:00   1770109200   10
13FEB2016T12:00   1770984000    6
21FEB2016T09:30   1771666200    6**
15MAR2016T12:00   1773662400    6**
20MAR2016T12:00   1774094400    5

**This value was carried forward.
```

Is it possible for the first record for a company to have a missing value? I'm guessing no, but if so (And probably just to be safe) consider this so that the previous company's data is not carried forward:

```
data LOCF;
  retain LOCF;
  set RAW;
  by company daten;
  if val ne . then LOCF=val;
  if ^first.company & val=. then val=LOCF;
  drop LOCF;
run;
```

Comment: Well done. I searched for LOCF in SAS everywhere and got a bunch of complicated solutions all requiring a group identifier to already exist. This has been a lifesaver!